# Finding the path to a contacts image in Objective-C on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

I was wondering if there was someway to find the file path of a contacts image?

I'm familiar with the functions ABPersonCopyImageData and ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat.

Those don't return the actual path to the image though. I was wondering if this was even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not possible.  Even if it were possible, it wouldn't matter, because your application only has access to the files in its own application sandbox.  The address book is stored outside of your application's sandbox.  So even if you had the path you couldn't access the file.